# How to be notified when Spark Streaming application is started?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I use Spark 2.3 (HDP 2.3.0.2.6.5.108-1) and [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) (`JavaInputDStream`).

I am writing a test of some component that use spark streaming. What I am trying to do is:

1. start the component in a separate thread, which start spark streaming
2. wait it is started
3. send a notification in kafka (read by spark)
4. wait it is processed
5. validate the outputs

However, I am stuck on the (2) and I don't know how I can at least check the streaming job has started. Is there any api that I can use?

Notes:

- I only have access to the spark context, not the streaming one... So it would be perfect if I could access such api from the spark context.
- the 3 comes after the 2 because setting spark auto.offset.reset` to earliest seams useless :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [SparkListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) interface and listen to the events emitted, e.g. `onApplicationStart`.

For Spark Streaming-specific events, use [StreamingListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListener) interface.

Comment: Sorry for the noise (and requesting a separate question), there's no need for it as I simply made a mistake offering you a generic SparkListener API not StreamingListener. Sorry about that. Fixed and should be exactly what you initially wanted.